# Using IF Statement in a Batch Script

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

I'm new to Batch Programming.I'm trying to use an IF Condition in one of my Batch Script.The Code looks like this.

```
:rmfile
:: removes the file based on it's age.
::                     
SETLOCAL
set file=%~1
set age=%~2
set thrshld_days=40
if %age% LSS 40 
echo.%file% is %age% days old 
EXIT /b
```

Now the Problem is that even if the age of a file is more than 40 i'm getting the file printed.which actually should not happen.

Please Help me in this regard..Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either put it on one line:

```
if %age% LSS 40 echo.%file% is %age% days old
```

or use block delimiters:

```
if %age% LSS 40 (
    echo.%file% is %age% days old
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if %age% LSS 40 
echo.%file% is %age% days old
```

is interpreted as conditional expression with empty body (first line) and unconditional `echo` (second line). You need to either put them on one line:

```
if %age% LSS 40 echo.%file% is %age% days old
```

or use parens to create block (but the opening bracket **must be on the same line** as `if`):

```
if %age% LSS 40 (
   echo.%file% is %age% days old
)
```

Comment: I tried with Parens as suggested but no luck :( Echo statement is getting printed for every file..